# How to Set a AD Computer Group Policy for Remote Desktop Logoff Delay Period?

Tags: active-directory, remote-desktop

Within an active directory domain, is there a computer group policy which can be set to control the delay period after a remote desktop session disconnect to automatically logoff the user? I am expressly interested doing so with recent WinSvr major releases.

Comment: To further clarify, which WinServer 2019 tool is used to set the security policy setting "Interactive logon: Machine inactivity limit" for all domain systems? I have searched "Group Policy Management" and "Active Directory Users and Computers" and haven't found it yet.

Comment: That is in addition to the "Remote Desktop Logoff Delay Period" for all domain systems. I need to log off users regardless of either being physically or virtually using a actual system, RDC to it or connecting to a VM after a set period of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be using the Group Policy Management tool to set an AD GPO.  Make sure you load the Admin templates (.admx) for the Windows versions you use  so you can access newer options in the GUI.

Comment: The issue I was having was that the actual editing tool today has to be accessed via the Group Policy Management which doesn't display the parameter. I found the edit context menu finally.

Comment: Your "Admin templates (.admx) for the Windows versions you use so you can access newer options in the GUI." comment was useful.

Answer (score 0):

The [Microsoft AD docu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/manage-group-policy) defines GPOs as follows

> Settings for user and computer objects in *Azure Active Directory Domain Services* (Azure AD DS) are often managed using *Group Policy Objects* (GPOs). Azure AD DS includes built-in GPOs for the *AADDC Users* and *AADDC Computers* containers.

It looks like you are after a special configuration of a GPO for a computer, and more specifically the **Session Time Limit**, see https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/118889-remote-desktop-set-time-limit-idle-sessions.html

#### Further reading

- [Serverfault: Remote desktop sessions - Unwanted automatic log off after period of time](https://serverfault.com/questions/99258/remote-desktop-sessions-unwanted-automatic-log-off-after-period-of-time)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/interactive-logon-machine-inactivity-limit

Comment: Let me know what you think, and whether you really have been only after the term.

Comment: I had seen the last which was the reference that I was trying to use. The problem seems that I am using WinSvr 2019 and all the references are 2010+- GPE based. The references don't seem present in 2019 GPE.

In the Serverfault reference, they are suggesting  registry or TSC modifications  by computer , not a group policy.

Comment: Does this help you: https://serverfault.com/questions/79418/enforcing-lock-screen-after-idle-time-via-gpo

Comment: Or this: https://www.ryadel.com/en/remote-desktop-session-time-limit-how-to-set-idle-timeout-in-windows-server-2012/